# Returning the URL Value of Hyperlink After Searching Webpage For Specific Hyperlink in Python

Tags: python-3.x, hyperlink, web-scraping, lxml, urllib

My objective is that I am writing a script designed to download the jpg file contained in a link on a picture wallpaper site. To achieve this, I wanted to basically search a webpage for a hyperlink (defined by a variable, here it is screenres for screen resolution) as this specific website lists out different resolutions for the file. After searching the webpage for the hyperlink (example: 1280x800), I want to return the value of the hyperlink in the form of the url (example: www.testwallpaperwebsite.com/image1020x800.jpg). I would then pass this to other tools to download the jpg. So far, this is the code I have which returns all of the url links on the webpage, but I cant seem to find a method that lets me search for the hyperlink and return just that url:

```
import urllib.request
import lxml.html

screenres = 1280x800 # this is the hyperlink I am trying to find on webpage, however variable can change depending on screen size
connection = urllib.request.urlopen("www.testwallpaperwebsite.com")
dom =  lxml.html.fromstring(connection.read())
for link in dom.xpath('//a/@href'): 
    print(link)
```

I have found many answers on Stack Overflow about retrieving URLS but nothing that can help me to specifically search for a hyperlink and extract its URL. Is there a way for it to recognize if a group of characters, like my variable, is a hyperlink in the first place? Granted, I am newer to Python and webscraping so I am still trying to get a handle on the mechanics of extracting information. Furthermore, if this simple task could be accomplished by using just urllib/lxml/other native modules rather than downloading BeautifulSoup, that would be great. However, if there is no other way, or it would be extremely complicated to do it otherwise, I could definitely download and use BeautifulSoup; just wanted to try and reduce the script's complexity. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Give us the HTML code around and including the desired hyperlink. You can disguise the domain of the website if you think you must but we need this information because the code needed to winkle out what you want can vary depending on how the url is embedded in the HTML. For instance, one of the sites one might wish to scrape has code like this `<li><a href="/size/1280x1024/"><span class="FCU">3619</span>1280x1024</a></li>`. Yours could be quite different.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely try `BeautifulSoup`. Check out their documentation [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). You can find images by using something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile("YOUR REGEX")
```

Comment: Ok, but how can one use bs4 to find hyperlinks? I don't need to run a regex as I already have the exact value I need to match. I just want it to find the hyperlink tag "1280x800" (like it would appear on a webpage) and give me the URL associated with it. All of bs4's documentation talks about much more complex extraction of multiple urls and regex search functions and I guess I'm getting bogged down. Is there a simple way you know to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You can use the following to find all hyperlinks: `soup.find_all("a")`